# Android Studio: Gradle Fatal Error

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I would like to give a go to Android Studio Beta version. I downloaded the SDK on their official site and launched the studio.exe.

I simply entered all the required fields for creating a New Test Project. Uppong building the project, I receive an error:

[image: GRADDLE ERROR]

I followed some advices from stack overlow, this is what I have already done:

- Installed appropriate JDK and set it up in Advanced Computer Settings
- Reinstalled the Android Studio
- Reinstalled the Android Studio with seperately installing Android SDK and updating it

Hope someon can help me out!